# Browser fails to load some websites with Static IP internet connection

Tags: router, nat, static-ip, not-responding

We are using static IP internet connection and we have connected 4 computers with single internet connection using NAT/Router device.  The problem is that when we try to load some websites, *e.g.* [AWS](https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/registration/index.html), the website is not loading completely and it loads like below and hangs.

[image]

When we try loading this page with other network connection from another location it is loading perfectly like below.

[image]

This makes sure that the website is not loading properly only on my network and also i checked on almost all browsers like Firefox, Chrome, IE, Safari and Opera but every thing fails to load in all systems connected in my network. Help me to sort it out.

Comment: So of those 4 computers, if you connect one to the Internet through a different ISP (like taking a laptop to a WiFi hotspot) does it work or no still? Is it all 4 computers, or just some of them, what software (browser and OS)? What kind of router? Shady or major ISP?

Answer (score 4):

Amazon and other sites host their images on separate servers and something is preventing you from accessing it.  I had this problem with my webfilter and had to make changes to allow the image servers to be accessed.  Barring that, you could have something wrong in your NAT configuration, or as MarkM says DNS, and Wireshark would be a good tool to use at that point.

Comment: Good call with filtering.

Comment: +1, Beat me, I noted the same, deleting answer. Images and favicon are missing in his screen shot.  Domains are: Images - https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com Favicon - http://awsmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/favicon.ico  Mixing HTTP/HTTPs could also trigger some security settings.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be DNS related. You can load the page from Amazon, but none of the stuff that would come from their CDN like images seem to be loading.

Can you look at the properties for some of the failing images and see where they should be loading from and dig/nslookup those domains? If it fails or acts strangely, you probably are having DNS issues.